# Nested list to dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to create `dict` by nested `list`:

```
groups = [['Group1', 'A', 'B'], ['Group2', 'C', 'D']]

L = [{y:x[0] for y in x if y != x[0]} for x in groups]
d = { k: v for d in L for k, v in d.items()}

print (d)
{'B': 'Group1', 'C': 'Group2', 'D': 'Group2', 'A': 'Group1'}
```

But it seems a bit complicated.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I see what you did there :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/43227053/5811078

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What about:

```
d = {k:row[0] for row in groups for k in row[1:]}
```

This gives:

```
>>> {k:row[0] for row in groups for k in row[1:]}
{'D': 'Group2', 'B': 'Group1', 'C': 'Group2', 'A': 'Group1'}
```

So you iterate over **every `row`** in the `groups`. The first element of the row is taken as value (`row[0]`) and you iterate over `row[1:]` to obtain all the keys `k`.

Weird as it might seem, this expression *also works* when you give it an empty row (like `groups = [[],['A','B']]`). That is because `row[1:]` will be empty and thus the `row[0]` part is *never* evaluated:

```
>>> groups = [[],['A','B']]
>>> {k:row[0] for row in groups for k in row[1:]}
{'B': 'A'}
```

Comment: super post on list comprehension.

Answer (score 10):

I think one line solution is a bit confusion. I would write code like below

```
groups = [['Group1', 'A', 'B'], ['Group2', 'C', 'D']]

result = {}
for group in groups:
    for item in group[1:]:
        result[item] = group[0]
print result
```

Comment: much better. Most of the time,1 line solutions are just to showcase cleverness

Answer (score 10):

This is essentially a prettier version of Willem's:

```
>>> groups = [['Group1', 'A', 'B'], ['Group2', 'C', 'D']]
>>> {k:g for g,*tail in groups for k in tail}
{'B': 'Group1', 'A': 'Group1', 'C': 'Group2', 'D': 'Group2'}
```

But it won't work with an empty list:`groups = [[],['A','B']]`

```
>>> {k:head for head, *tail in grps for k in tail}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1, got 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

I also like Willem's solution, but just for completeness...

another variation using itertools and a generator function (Python 3.x only)

```
def pairs(groups):
    for value,*keys in groups:
        for key_value in zip(keys, itertools.repeat(value)): 
            yield key_value

dict(pairs(groups))
{'A': 'Group1', 'B': 'Group1', 'C': 'Group2', 'D': 'Group2'}
```